# Datadog with JMX, datadog docker image does not have java installed

Tags: java, docker, jmx, datadog

I am attempting to use Datadog to monitor my application via JMX... I have successfully deployed my app in a docker container, and exposed the JMX port and confirmed I can indeed attach to the port from anywhere and get information.

So I am attempting to set up the datadog docker image to use JMX and connect to the server... I have it all configured, but at runtime the datadog image attempts to start utilizing JMX, but fails saying it can't find Java on its image... I log into the image and sure enough it has no java installed.

From the datadog documentation:

```
 Java Path
The agent does not come with a bundled JVM, but will use the one installed on 
your system. Therefore you must make sure that the Java home directory is 
present in the path of the user running the agent.

Alternatively, you can specify the JVM path in the integration’s configuration 
file:

java_bin_path: /path/to/java
```

Well that's all nice and well, but if I attempt to expose my host machine java to the image via a volume mount, it doesn't work, as the host machine is Apple and if the image attempts to run the java binary it throws an invalid format for the binary file.. not surprising since its a MACOS binary not a Debian Linux Binary (which the datadog image is)....

So, I have been attempting to take the datadog image and build a new image with it as the base with Java... but I have been completely unsuccessful, every attempt to install java during docker build fails.. I have tried every example of how to install java into a debian docker image, but none work... Every one dies with apt-get line returned a non zero

How the heck do I get JAVA installed on a debian image?

Or better yet, how do I get the datadog image with JMX to run properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is a datadog/agent:latest-jmx that should be used that contains the java image... I just missed it in the docs.